# $H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q})$ is free abelian

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to show that $H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q})$ is free abelian, this is another exercise in Hatcher.

I'm not sure but I thought I can use the exact sequence

$$ \cdots 0 \xrightarrow{f} H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) \xrightarrow{g} H_0(\mathbb{Q}) \xrightarrow{h} H_0(\mathbb{R}) \xrightarrow{i} \cdots$$

and then

$$ 0 \xrightarrow{f} H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) \xrightarrow{g} H_0(\mathbb{Q}) \xrightarrow{h} \operatorname{ker} (i) \xrightarrow{i}0$$

My idea is to use that an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C  \rightarrow$ splits if $C$ is free. So I thought because $\operatorname{ker}(i)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, it's free. If this is correct, all I need to finish is $H_0(\mathbb{Q})$. I think it should be a countable infinite direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$'s but I don't know how to express that. How about $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$?

Then I'd have $H_0(\mathbb{Q}) = H_1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(i)$ and therefore $H_1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}) \cong H_0(\mathbb{Q})  / \operatorname{ker}(i) \cong H_0(\mathbb{Q})$.

Now I'm supposed to find a basis for that.

Can someone tell me if my calculations are correct and if yes give me a hint on how to find a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$? Many thanks for your help!

**Edit**
I just found out we have the following exact sequence:
$$0 \rightarrow H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) \xrightarrow{f} H_0(\mathbb{Q}) \xrightarrow{g} H_0(\mathbb{R}) \xrightarrow{h} 0$$

Using the previous exercise, 16 (a), I know that $H_0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ meets every path-component of $\mathbb{R}$. I also have $H_0(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{Z}$.

**Edit 2**

OK, I think I have it:

$$ H_0( \mathbb{Q} )  = \oplus_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Z} $$

$$ g: \oplus_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Z}  \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$

$$ \operatorname{im}{g} = \mathbb{Z} \implies \operatorname{ker}{g} = \oplus_{q \in \mathbb{Q} - \ast} \mathbb{Z}$$

Here $\mathbb{Q} - \ast$ should be the rationals minus a point.

$$ H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) / 0 = H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) = \operatorname{im}{f} =  \oplus_{q \in \mathbb{Q} - \ast} \mathbb{Z}$$

Can you tell me if this is correct?

What is a basis for this?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: since you have not told us what $Q-*$ is (in fact, that "proof" does not contain any words at all...), it is impossible to know what you are trying to say.

Comment: I updated it, that should be the rationals minus a point.

Comment: You have not described the map $g$: it is not the projection onto one of the direct summands of $H_0(R,Q)$.

Comment: But I don't need to have $g$ explicitly. All I need is its kernel and I can compute that without knowing $g$. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Oh! I just noticed that you edited your answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A subgroup of a free abelian group is free abelian, by a well known theorem of Kaplanski.

That fact and the long exact sequence do the trick.

**Later.** $\newcommand\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand\RR{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}$Let's "compute" $H_1(\RR,\QQ)$.

We know that the path-connected components of $\QQ$ are the points. It follows from the general description of $H_0$ that if we denote, for each $q\in\QQ$, $[q]_\QQ$ the homology class in $H_0(\QQ)$ of the point $q$ and $\ZZ[q]_\QQ$ the subgroup it generates in $H_0(\QQ)$, then there is an isomorphism $$H_0(\QQ)\cong\bigoplus_{q\in\QQ}\ZZ[q]_\QQ$$

We also know that $H_0(\RR)$ is free abelian of rank one, generated by the homology class of any point; moreover, we know that if $x$ and $y$ are points in $\RR$ and we denote $[x]_\RR$ and $[y]_\RR$ their homology classes in $H_0(\RR)$, then $[x]_\RR=[y]_\RR$.

Now, the map $g$ is induced by the inclusion $\QQ\to\RR$. In other words, for each $q\in\QQ$ we have $$g([q]_\QQ)=[q]_\RR.$$ In fact, since the set $\{[q]_\QQ:q\in\QQ\}$ is a basis of the abelian group $H_0(\QQ)$, this information completely determines the map $g$.

Next, and as you observed, there is a short exact sequence $$0\to H_1(\RR,\QQ)\xrightarrow fH_0(\QQ)\xrightarrow gH_0(\RR)$$ coming from the long exact sequence inhomology for the pair $(\RR,\QQ)$. We therefore obtain a description of $H_1(\RR,\QQ)$ as an abelian group isomorphic to the kernel of the map $g$.

Can you construct a basis of $\ker g$?

Comment: thank you! But what about my computations? Is $H_0(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Matt, $H_0$ of a space is the free abelian group on the path components of the space. What are the path components of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm very insecure about. Is it or is it not, $\mathbb{q_i}$? Every point in $\mathbb{Q}$ is a path-component of it I think. But then I'd have $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ and I'm not sure about that...

Comment: *Why* would you have $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$, the direct product of countably many copies of $\mathbb Z$? (You don't, by the way)

Comment: In any case, you should get rid of any insecurities about what are the path components of $\mathbb Q$ before continuing... Describe all continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Because every path-component (i.e. point $q_i$) generates a homology group that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Then I do $H_0(\mathbb{Q}) = \oplus H_0(q_i) = \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Every continuous function has to be constant, equal to $q_i$?

Comment: @Matt, when one writes $\mathbb Z^A$ with $A$ an infinite set, that means the *direct product* of copies of $\mathbb Z$, one per element in $A$; what you get, on the other hand, is a *direct sum*.

Comment: Don't ask me: give me a proof! :)

Comment: If it maps to more than one point, say to two, $q_1, q_2$, then for every delta their distance will be greater equals $|q_1 - q_2|$. So pick epsilon smaller than this distance and you cannot find a delta such that continuity holds...

Comment: So what's the difference between the direct sum and the direct product in this case? I thought they were the same!

Comment: You should try to prove in detail that every continuous function  $[0,1]\to\mathbb Q$ is constant---what you wrote is not a correct argument. This *is* important: homology theory is a complicated elaboration of that very fact!

Comment: The difference between a direct product and a direct sum is stated, for example, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Properties

Comment: There are so many words I don't know the definition of! But so $H_0(\mathbb{Q}) = \oplus_{q_i} \mathbb{Z}$? Would that be correct if I wrote it like that?

Comment: OK, I have a better argument. Continuous functions map connected spaces to connected spaces. $[0,1]$ is connected, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not, therefore there cannot be a continuous function $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The difference between product and sum is that sums allow only for strings with finite support, but products allow for infinite support; support is the number of non-zero terms in the string.

Comment: Assume there is , e.g., a continuous function $f$: from $X$ connected into ${0,1}$ discrete. Then each of {$0$}, {$1$} is open in {$0,1$}, so that each of their respective inverse images is open in X. Then $f^{-1} 0  \cup f^{-1}  1 $ is a disconnection of X. But not only is $\mathbb Q$ not connected; it is, as you said _totally disconnected_ , i.e., its components are the singletons.

Comment: Note that I am not saying that the rationals are a discrete space; they are not (e.g., singletons are not open), it was just an idea for the proof.

Comment: Dear Matt, I just want to emphasize Mariano's point above: you should abandon thinking about this problem for the moment, and focus on computing the path components of $\mathbb Q$. This is something that can be proved from first principles, just using the ideas of an undergrad real analysis course.  Regards,

Comment: So a basis for $\operatorname{ker}{g}$ is $\{ [q]_\mathbb{Q} : q \in \mathbb{Q} - \ast \}$?